# Calling a PHP function from same PHP file throught AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call php function through Ajax in same php file.
User enter `voucher_id` then call ajax that ajax call php function that function is in same file.
How to call that function.

**function of PHP code:-**

```
function voucherExist($voucherNo, $sCID, $type){
        global $pncon;
        $uRow = $pncon->query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE voucher_no = '{$voucherNo}' AND company_ID = '{$sCID}' AND type = '{$type}'");
        return $uRow;
    }
```

**Ajax code:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $('#voucher_no').on('change', function () {
                    var voucher_no = $('#voucher_no').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "bankVoucherAddEdit.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: "voucherNo"
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: fiunction name is **voucherExist**

Comment: You need to put exact URL, Something like http://localhost/folder/bankVoucherAddEdit.php (I assume you work on your local)
Be careful about the SQL injection as well.

Comment: you cannot call PHP functions from the same file as Ajax is in. You must have it in another file and call it from there instead.

Comment: You want to enter `voucher_id` in `text box` without submit form with `submit button click`  and then get the data based results on that `voucher_id`???

Comment: @Uzair Ahmed your problem is solved or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an idea from the below:

```
<? php 
    function yourFunction($data){
    
     return $data;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['voucherNo'])) {
        echo yourFunction($_POST['voucherNo']);
    }
?>

<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'bankVoucherAddEdit.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { "voucherNo": voucher_no },
        success: function(response) { console.log(response); }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ahmed I'm not submit form. This is working on change in textbox.

Comment: You can use the snippet inside your change event. It will work the same in the change event. Just copy the ajax code try it in your change event

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you cannot directly call a PHP function from JS. You can achieve this by RESTful API. They are quite simpler and Standard.

In your case, Send any post value as a flag from JS to PHP, if that POST value exists then call PHP function